# Pros and cons of using AngularJS + jQuery Mobile in one project

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

We're about to start a project using mentioned libraries. We have already used jQM in another project, but coupled with Backbone. Now we're thinking about using AngularJS with jQM. Do you think it's a good idea? And if not, why?

To elaborate, the question is whether it is advisable/recommended/easy/beneficial to use these libraries together, or maybe there is something that should prevent us from using them both in one project. We don't want to spend half of project's time on making them work together just on principle.

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter? It provides pretty deep integration between the two. Haven't checked it out though.

Comment: Your comment doesn't answer the question. But yes, we have checked the adapter out.

Comment: That's why it's a comment. By the way, Stackoverflow is not a very good place for pro / contra or "discussion" questions

Comment: This is my first question here on SO. I'm sorry if it's not correctly formulated.

Comment: I came across your question having the same concerns. I imagine you've now had some time to work with the libraries. Did you have any issues working with them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AngularJS and JQM do different things. AngularJS is MVC + Lot More. JQM on the other hand is for direct UI manipulation (lower level than Angular). The good news is AngularJS is flexible and will let you work with any other Javascript framework including JQM. The recommended way of using them together is use the adapter as mentioned above or create your own reusable `directives` that will add "JQM nature" to your views. For e.g. you can create a directive that will convert a standard `UL` to a fancier JQM list. The good thing about doing this in `directives` and not within your view is that your UI code is separated in separate modules and not intermingled with business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That's what we're trying to do at the moment. I'm just wondering if there are any landmines along the way...

Comment: Can you advise a specific library that provide these directives?

Comment: Hi - a "landmine" I'm hitting right now is todo with URLs and routing. Basically I'm trying to use the `ng-include` directive to pull in an external (but still bundled in the app) header file. THIS causes my other links (jQM style `#somePage`) to get buggered somehow. I'm looking at that mentioned adapter now to see if that solves anything. I have not yet tried the full blown custom directive approach.

Comment: Hm, seems that adapter is not being maintained anymore (not the old one, and not the new one). SO much for that then.